# React State Vs Storing Data

Tags: reactjs, object, state, use-state, use-ref

I want to store some data in my component across renders: eg

```
export default function ExampleComponent(){

  const [renderData, setRenderData] = useState("I am render data/state")

  let o = {
    question: "will this data persist through re-renders?"
  }

  render(
    <div>
      {renderData}
    </div>
  )

}
```

Is is safe to store data and update like this (o)? Or do I need to store it with a useRef hook? If this is the case, why?

My mental model is that useState is used to store data associated with the user interface render and re-renders and that the data of (o) object is not affected and persists.

UseRef is used for gaining access to and/or manipulating specific DOM elements.

Is this a correct assumption?

Steve

Comment: Sorry but where have you updated the data in your example?

Comment: No, useRef can be used when you want a mutable reference. A good hook to use for storing `o` or `question`

Comment: @RameshReddy Do I need to use useRef to store the object? Does (o) not persist across the re-renders if I update setRenderData? Or on re-render does React completely re-create the ExampleComponent component?

Comment: What do you mean by safe?

Comment: `o` will be redefined every time `ExampleComponent` renders.